# Installing postgres on Ubuntu 18.04 prompts for "Password:". Which Password should be supplied?

Tags: postgresql, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to create a scripted installation of Postgres on Ubuntu 18.04.06, using `bash`. In order to do this, I am using the following post from Digital Ocean as a starting point, and adapting it to my needs:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04

The account that I am using is a sudoer on the machine. I am running the following two lines - the problem occurs on the second line:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

The `apt update` completes successfully, then the `postgresql` install chugs along until it reaches this point:

```
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql_14+238.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (14+238.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-common (238.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (238.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Password:
```

I have tried entering the password to my sudoer account - all it does is hang. I have also tried just hitting `ENTER` - no dice.

I can see from the docs and the `/etc/passwd` file that the Postgres install process creates a `postgres` unix account automatically. If the `Password:` prompt is asking for the password to this `postgres` account, I don't know where to find this password either.

To summarize:

- Can this `Password:` prompt be avoided entirely?
- If the prompt can't be avoided, where do I find the correct password?

Thanks !

Comment: If you are still in the install process it is asking you for the password you want to use. If already installed you may want to try *postgres* as the password.

Comment: What repo are you getting this from? What happens if you try without the `-y`?

Comment: You haven't described configuring the PGDG repository, and the guide you link to doesn't either.  So why is it installing from pgdg rather than from ubuntu?

Comment: " I have also tried just hitting ENTER - no dice."   I gather it didn't work, but what is it that happened instead of "dice"?

Comment: @jjanes Thanks. After pressing ENTER it simply hung. Same as when entering password for sudoer account.

Comment: I have never had the Postgres package ask me for a password at that stage. The package will set up a `postgres` user, but it will not have a `/home/postgres/` directory nor will it have a password. To confirm look at `/etc/shadow` as `sudo` user.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem on Debian 11.  Turns out it was because I had `su` disabled in `/etc/pam.d/su`

To reverse that in `/etc/pam.d/su`

Uncomment
`auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so`

And comment out
`auth       required   pam_wheel.so use_uid`